# Is convolution the only way to apply filters?

Tags: filters, convolution

I've read about the discrete convolution and how it applies to filters, but is convolution the only way to apply filters (to input signals)?

Comment: The answer is "kind of". Covolution in the time domain leads to FIR and IIR filters. There also is the multiplication in the frequency domain, but that equals convolution in the time domain:
$$
x(t)*y(t) => X(f)\cdot Y(F)
$$

In the end, everything can be traced back to one form of convolution or another.

Comment: @JanKrüger Is then for example the direct evaluation of direct forms also convolution? Such as what Matlab's filter() claims to do.

Comment: @mavavilj what else should it be? Have you read the mathematical expression that `filter` computes? It's a discrete convolution!

Comment: @mavavilj Yes, it is. Convolution is nothing else than a mathematical operation, constructed from an integral (which, in essence, is a sum), one signal (the filter kernel for example) turned around ($0..k => k..0$) and a multiplication. This is also what Matlabs filter() does. This is also what hardware filters do, no matter how they are arranges (one MAC cycling over the whole signal, FIR/IIR transversal, etc).

Comment: by the way, we're only considering digital, linear filters, right? because there are other types of filters, but they are kind of rarely used, and especially Matlab's `filter` has nothing to do with them.

Comment: By the way, your question sounds a lot like the good old [**X/Y problem**](http://xyproblem.info/) . Maybe you want to open another question, explaining *why* you're wondering whether filtering is convolution.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, I'm trying to ask whether convolution is all that's needed to know for "applying filters" or whether there are other application methods.

Comment: Well, it's not the only way of "applying" a filter, but all other methods than convolution are 100% mathematically equivalent to convolution. So, I guess your question is answered? I have another question for you then: **Why** are you asking this?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Because I wanted to be sure that my intuition about convolution being the only one was right.

Comment: Just to add a bit of precision: the use of convolution to calculate a system's output is valid only when the system is LTI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this discussion it's important to restrict the class of filters to linear time-invariant (LTI) filters. Their input-output relation is described by the standard convolution sum (or, in continuous-time, convolution integral) that you've probably come across. So the operation of any LTI system can be described by a convolution. In discrete time you have

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}h[k]x[n-k]\tag{1}$$

where $x[n]$ is the input signal, $h[n]$ is the system's impulse response, and $y[n]$ is the output signal. An example where $(1)$ is implemented directly is the transversal filter, which has a finite impulse response (FIR).

However, this doesn't mean that an LTI system can only be implemented by directly implementing the convolution sum ($1$). Any infinite impulse response (IIR) must be implemented recursively, because the convolution sum $(1)$ can't be computed exactly in finite time (since it's an infinite sum). But mathematically, any recursive implementation of an IIR filter computes the same thing as the convolution sum.

The convolution sum can also be implemented in the frequency domain, where blocks of data are transformed using the DFT, these frequency domain data are modified according to the desired impulse response, and after applying an IDFT, the data blocks are combined to give the desired output signal. Two such methods are the [overlap add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) and the [overlap save](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) methods.

In sum, all LTI systems are described by a convolution sum (or integral), but there are many ways to implement that sum, and more often than not, the convolution sum is not evaluated directly.

Comment: So is there something else than LTI systems, in digital filters?

Comment: @mavavilj: Sure, why not?

Comment: @mavavilj: E.g., adaptive filters, non-linear filters, etc.

Comment: So then the answer to my question should be "yes, but only for LTI systems"?

Comment: @mavavilj: Well, the problem is that your formulation "the only way to apply filters" is a bit unclear. Does "apply" mean implement? My answer should clarify all those details, please read it (again), and ask questions if necessary. Especially the last sentence of the answer should actually make things clear.

Comment: Apply means to apply the filter to the input signal.

Comment: @mavavilj: Sure, but do you mean in an actual implementation, or on paper? Again, my answer (hopefully) addresses and clarifies all those details. I don't understand what is still unclear to you.

Comment: Why would actual implementation differ from paper?

Comment: @mavavilj: Did you read my answer? E.g., it says "Any infinite impulse response (IIR) must be implemented recursively, because the convolution sum (1) can't be computed exactly in finite time". So on paper you can write down the convolution sum, but in practice you don't have the time to sum an infinite number of terms.

Comment: But what about discrete convolution.

Comment: @mavavilj: Eq (1) is discrete, otherwise it should be an integral.

Comment: Perhaps I meant finite convolution.

Comment: @mavavilj: If you have a discrete-time convolution with a finite length impulse response (FIR), then you *can* compute the convolution sum directly, but you don't need to (you can also do a frequency domain implementation. Again, all of this is in my answer (see the second paragraph from the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

What is a filter anyway? In every-day life:

> a device that is used to remove something unwanted from a (generally) fluid
>   substance

In computer programming?

> a program or section of code that is designed to examine each input or output request for certain qualifying criteria

In data processing, we are somehow inbetween. The fluid substance (signal) should be removed from something unwanted not satisfying some qualifying criteria (noise).

Depending on the criteria, you have many choices, depending on assmptions. For instance median, min-max filtering, all depending on certain qualifying criteria.

If you trust in filtering that does not depend on the actual time, and that is linear (the sum of two filtered signals is the filtering of the sum of two signals), you get "linear time_invariant filtering" (LTI). Then, one quickly understands this is strongly related to Fourier basis and convolution. Many other sources can provide you with insights:

- [What are the advantages of LTI ( Linear Time Invariant ) systems over other systems?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31304/what-are-the-advantages-of-lti-linear-time-invariant-systems-over-other-syst)
- [Intuition behind the convolution of two functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284794/intuition-behind-the-convolution-of-two-functions)
- [Understanding the convolution in signals and systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730389/understanding-the-convolution-in-signals-and-systems)

Then, you can apply linear filters the convolutive way. But thanks to the above Fourier relation, you can apply them in the Fourier domain, using recursive filters, with lattice formulations, etc. All of them ultimately yield linear filters, but the different implementations vary in efficiency, complexity, economy, robusness to errors, etc.